# Retrieve CASE SENSITIVE Windows command 'whoami' Username

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using WinAutomation and I am trying to point to and open a file on any computer that my software is placed on without having to hard-code the username in the path, so I am looking for a way to retrieve the logged in Username, that will be case sensitive so I can grab that variable.

Using the Windows command line, (which I can run invisible to the user in the background) if the username in the file tree is "User Name", whoami will return "user name" and then,

If I point to a file `C:\Users\%pcName%\Desktop\Masterlist.xlsx` with that `%pcName%` not correctly capitalized it will not work...

I saw a question about Pythonic way to retrieve case sensitive path but I can't use Python for this. I am open to creative ways to get the case sensitive User Name but I keep seeing people deciding to enforce lowercase usernames as a solution.

**Is there a way to find the case-sensitive logged in users name for use in file path references?** *I'm open to being creative at this point!!*

Comment: Nobody said that the profile directories are under c:\Users - in facts, under e.g. Windows XP or under any PC in a domain with profile directory on a server they won't be there. At bare minimum, you should use `%userprofile%` (although it's still not correct if you want to ask for the desktop location).

Comment: @Ross, while I can appreciate your tenacity at editing my post, to remove the DOS tags and the use in my question, the function in winautomation, (the program that I am using and asking about), is literally "Run DOS Command", so it may be helpful to others looking to find this solution, to re-include it.

Comment: If you had literally used the phrase "Run DOS Command" in your question to refer to a specific function with that specific name, then yes, it would have been a mistake to for me to remove it from your post. However DOS is an old obsolete 16-bit operating system with no concept of user names or running things in background. The fact that application you're using mistakenly refers to the Windows command line as "DOS" does't change this. You can edit the incorrect use of the word DOS back into your post if you insist, but the [dos] tag is only to be used for questions about MS-DOS and its clones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me make clear that your request is probably an [XY issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to achieve something and it *looks like* the solution is to fix the casing in the user name. However, there are several argument against that:

1. Windows file names are not case sensitive. It should not matter what casing you use. Maybe some other component compares these names in a case sensitive way where it shouldn't. In that case, the component should be fixed.
2. User names in Windows are not case sensitive. You can log on with any casing.
3. You're constructing a path `C:\Users\%pcname%`, which looks like `%USERPROFILE%`. However, a user profile is not necessarily in `C:\Users`. It could have been moved anywhere.

It's unclear to me, what exactly "does not work" and for which reason. You don't specify an error message which could let me diagnose the root cause, so we could fix the real problem.

You say that you can't use Python, but you do not specify any other programming language that you can use, so let me treat [dos](/questions/tagged/dos) as an equivalent of [batch](/questions/tagged/batch).

Whatever your real problem is, `echo %username%` does what you ask for:

```
C:\Users\For example John>echo %username%
For example John
```

But be warned: in 90+% of the cases, this is not the correct approach.

In C#, you would use

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

for the user profile and

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

for the Desktop.

Comment: This is bad advice. Using the username environment variable to construct the path to a user's profile directory is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I updated the answer to make that point more clear.

Comment: If this is correctly returning the username, why is this wrong in 90% of the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Winautomation has a function, "**Get Special folder**" that will return the filepath to the Desktop of the current PC as a variable. That variable can then be used as the root of whatever you are trying to access.

This is the correct way to reach the Desktop file path and does not require any special DOS usage.

Answer (score 0):

'Desktop' is a User Shell Folder. The value for these folders is stored in the registry, with the right case :-).
The registry can be queried from the command prompt using 'reg query'.

If you just want the data value of the Desktop property, use the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop ^| findstr "REG_"') do @echo %b
```